# How to parse time string without date and date string without time?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Is there any way to automatically parse strings with time only to `datetime.time` object (or something similar)? Same for `datetime.date`.

I've tried [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/), [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow), [moment](https://github.com/zachwill/moment), [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).
All these parsers create timestamps with a current date.

```py
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('23:53')
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 8, 23, 53)  # datetime.time(23, 53) expected
>>> parse('2018-01-04')
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 0, 0)  # datetime.date(2018, 1, 4) expected
```

**UPD:**

Thanks for the responses. Think that I should clarify the problem.

The program doesn't know what will be in the input (`timestamp`, `date` or `time`), and it should decide to set appropriate type. The problem is to distinguish these types.

For example, I can parse `23:53` and get a timestamp. How can I decide to extract the time from it or not?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.fromisoformat) from `datetime`.

```
import datetime
datetime.time.fromisoformat('23:53')
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2018-01-04')
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `fromisoformat()` wasn't added until Python 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

What you basically want is for '23:53' to become a `datetime.time` object and for '2018-01-04' to become a `datetime.date` object. This cannot be achieved by using `dateutil.parser.parse()`:

> Returns a `datetime.datetime` object or, if the `fuzzy_with_tokens` option is `True`, returns a tuple, the first element being a `datetime.datetime` object, the second a tuple containing the fuzzy tokens.

From the [documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html). So you'll always get a datetime.datetime object when using `dateutil.parser.parse()`

I would guess you need to interpret the input string yourself to define wether you're trying to parse a time or a date. When you do that, you can still use the `dateutil.parser.parse()` function to get the object you want:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
my_time = parse('23:53')
my_time.time()  # datetime.time(23, 53)
my_time.date()  # datetime.date(2019, 1, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example. Just set the date attributes with replace, and select the output with strftime.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now()
newdate = date.replace(hour=11, minute=59)
print(newdate.strftime('%H:%M'))
newdate2 = date.replace(year=2014, month=1, day=3)
print(newdate2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either time or datetime modules, but one thing to bear in mind, is that these always create an object, that specifies a moment in time. (Also, if parsing strings, consider using the strptime function and displaying as string, strftime function respectively)

e.g.

```
>>> hours = time.strptime("23:59", "%H:%M")
>>> days = time.strptime("2018-01-04", "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M", hours)
'23:59'
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M %Y", hours)
'23:59 1900'
```

Not recommended, but if you wish to separate these two object for some reason and wish to only care for a specific portion of your assignement, you can still adress the respective numbers with

```
>>> hours.tm_hour
23
>>> hours.tm_min
59

>>> days.tm_mon
1
>>> days.tm_mday
4
>>> days.tm_year
2018
```

A far better approach, in my opinion would be formatting the complete date string and using the strptime to form a complete timestamp - even if you get the time and date as separate inputs:

```
>>> ttime = "22:45" 
>>> dday = "2018-01-04"
```

You can use the % formatter, or the "new" python f-Strings

```
>>> complete_t_string = "{} {}".format(dday, ttime)
>>> complete_t_string
'2018-01-04 22:45'
```

Now that we have a complete string, we can specify how it should be read and create a complete timestamp:

```
>>> complete_time = time.strptime(complete_t_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
>>> complete_time
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=4, tm_hour=22, tm_min=45, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=4, tm_isdst=-1)
```

EDIT:
Somebody will probably kill me, but if you absolutely know that you will only get two types of values, you could just do a simple try / except construct. It can probably be written more Pythonically:

```
try:
    time.strptime(t_string, "%H:%M")
except ValueError:
    time.strptime(t_string, "%Y-%m-%d")
```